# Possible changes to careers site employer pages?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs

I like the new feature in careers that gives you additional information regarding companies seeking employees.  For instance it's very nice to see the benefits, the location, the people we may work with and the technology stack.  But I was thinking of 2 separate incidents that happened to me while using the company pages.  One relates to "The People You'll Work With" and the other relates to "The Technology Stack".

**1) People You'll Work With**

Is it possible to make the people you'll work with clickable to their stackoverflow profile if and only if they have a profile?

Reason being is if I decide to join a specific company I'd like to see how my fellow peers are asking or answering questions.  This is very important in a team based environment.

**2) Technology stack tags**

Why do the technology tags appear as clickable and change style when you hover over them when you really can't click on them?  At first it appears if you click the tag you get more info, but nothing happens.

Comment: Could you separate your apparent feature request and support request? And then perhaps give them relevant titles?

Comment: @Bart trying to clean it up now.

Comment: I meant to separate it into two questions @JonH. But given Nick's answer, I guess we can leave it as is. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already support 1.  If they have a profile, there will be a link to it in the box that pops up when you hover over them.

Number 2 is a bug and I'll fix it up to be released later today.

Comment: Hi Nick, can you point me to a company page to verify #1?  I couldn't seem to find one.  Thanks for acknowledging the bug!

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange hover over any of us to see an orange link to our profiles

Comment: Okay so it gives you a link to their careers page which has the stackoverflow profile.  But what about people who dont have a careers page?  I assume they are never listed as "People you will work with" ?

Comment: A company can invite anyone they want to be in that section.  If the person has a public CV (as in public url) we will link it.  Otherwise we just show their name.

Comment: So I take it you cant just link to their SO profile in this case?  That is you guys only link to a career profile?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Is this by design (in addition, what you guys want based on feedback) or something you guys could consider?  SOme of the top stackoverflow members dont have a career page.

Comment: It is by design.  We don't want the same link to take you to different places depending on who it is you clicked on.  There is also the argument for linking to other places if we'd allow SO profiles, why not github?  Or something else?  A careers profile gives a more complete picture of who you will be working with and doesn't have any of those problems.

Comment: Okay thanks I see you fixed the tag bug problem, no more clickable or hovering effects looks good.  Thanks!